# How to to do a $project with the mongo C# 2.0 driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm facing a small issue with a projection in MongoDb.
I have a project in mongo shell that looks like the following:

```
{ $project: {
    "_id": 0,
    "ezBaseId": "$ezBaseId",
    "classificationId": "$_id.classificationId",
    "name": "$_id.name",
    "specification": "$_id.specification",
    "img": "$_id.img",
    "articles": "$articles",
    "supplier": "$_id.supplier"
}},
```

So, I'm not working with 1 and 0 here, but rather I'm creating new properties to match another property (used to unwrap the id field here).

But I'm stuck creating this in C#.

A basic projection goes like so:

```
.Project(Builders<Root>.Projection.Combine(
    Builders<Root>.Projection.Exclude(x => x.Id),
    Builders<Root>.Projection.Include(x => x.EzBaseId)
));
```

How can I add a field named "Demo" to the projection that contains a value from the original set?

Kind regards

Comment: Another chance to self solve. What have we learned from lambda expressions from previous topics?

Comment: But really here, I don't know where to create a named type. I'm a bit lost :-)

Comment: Should be something along those lines: .Project<Root, Root2>(root =>

Comment: Maybe I can just ask you another small question. When I create classes, how can I change the name of the property in the database. I tought by using `BsonElement` but that's not working.

Comment: I personally have not tried "re-assignment" with a lambda ever, and in fact I usually stay away from them and use the "traditional" approach since I find it suits my sensibilities and find the lambda to be overkill. I might try this weekend, and if it yields anything I think useful then I might post something about it.

Comment: Thx for that. What do you mean with the "traditional" approach? Using BsonDocument? But then you lose compile-ahead type checkings :)

Comment: Who cares? It's BSON. Type checking is a false concern here IMHO. We are talking about a "schemaless" data store after all. Therefore any enforced "schema" is merely just an illusion of the interacting API. And one that probably should not really be there in a lot of cases, though it does have it's uses of course.

Comment: I like it to avoid typing errors. Anyway, problem is solved by writing the project in a BSON right now. However, if you come across a solution using the typed variant, it would be nice if you can show it to me :-)

Comment: I understand the general concern here, and have come across many such "mistakes" in the SQL world. But this is honestly straying off-topic for the question that was asked. To which you found an answer no less.

Comment: Would you like me to create a new question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BlakesSeven, I've managed to find the solution myself.
I was strugling with the builders but it seems that it isn't needed in this particular case.

See the solution below:

```
.Project(root => 
    new Root2 {
        ezBaseId = root.EzBaseId,
        classificationId = root.Id.ClassificationId,
        name = root.Id.Name,
        specification = root.Id.Specification,
        img = root.Id.Image,
        articles = root.Articles,
        supplier = root.Id.Supplier
    });
```

I need to construct a new type from the projection.

@Blakes: If you want some reputation, please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I'd frankly rather people learned it themselves as you have here if it really should be a simple problem. Yes, the documentation is "lacking" in examples and poorly so. But the general principles for lambda expressions remain the same. And I do think they are overused. So if you wer able to learn and it helps others, then the "rep" is all yours.